# WordPress insecure content on ssl website

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I am facing problems with insecure content being loaded on ssl wordpress, everything rest is fine, and all the links are under https, but few things we are echo-ing are not showing as https. I tried with plugin to fix insecure content but that didn't work. Below is a code we use to get images which are showing as http instead of https. I wonder how can I force these images to load as https instead?

```
<?php
        $galleryImages = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'atak_portfolio_gallaryImages', true);
        if(is_array($galleryImages)){
            foreach($galleryImages as $galleryImage)
            {
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $galleryImage; ?>">
                    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1232" src="<?php echo $galleryImage; ?>" alt="project10-4" rel="lightbox" width="1024" height="673">
                </a>
            <?php

            }
        }
        ?>
```

And second one:

```
<?php
        $galleryImages = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'atak_portfolio_gallaryImages', true);
        if(is_array($galleryImages)){
            foreach($galleryImages as $galleryImage)
            {
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $galleryImage; ?>">
                    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1232" src="<?php echo $galleryImage; ?>" alt="project10-4" rel="lightbox" title="Atak Interactive Portfolio" width="1024" height="673">
                </a>
            <?php

            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Have you set your Site URL and Home URL properly in the admin?

Comment: Yes, I have set it properly from there.

Comment: Can you show the code where you set the post_meta. It looks like you are saving a http:// url in your (update|add)_post_meta call. Also don't forget to escape output, search for esc_url.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should strip URLs from http(s) protocols?

```
<?php
    $galleryImages = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'atak_portfolio_gallaryImages', true);
    if(is_array($galleryImages)){
        foreach($galleryImages as $galleryImage)
        {
            $galleryImage = preg_replace( '#http[s]?:#i', '', $galleryImage );
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $galleryImage; ?>">
                <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1232" src="<?php echo $galleryImage; ?>" alt="project10-4" rel="lightbox" title="Atak Interactive Portfolio" width="1024" height="673">
            </a>
        <?php

        }
    }
```

If I hadn't made mistake in preg_replace REGEX you should get URLs like `//your-site/.../image.png` and this should solve your problem.